# How to call the default handler from within an event handler

Tags: event-handling, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe5

I have a TStatusbar with 4 panels and one of them set in OwnerDraw style.

In the `onDrawPanel()` event handler, I would like the `TStatusbar` to use the default paint method before I add some custom drawing on top of it.

Is there a way I can call the default handler from my onDrawPanel handler?

**EDIT**
Well, I did found a fix, but I'm not sure how reliable it is if the system font change.
Since the default handler only draws the panel text, a simple call to TextRect will do the same trick.

```
StatusBar->Canvas->TextRect(Rect,Rect.Left,Rect.Top,Panel->Text);
```

But, I'm not sure how well this will work if the system font, language etc. isn't the default.

I would still like to get an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TStatusBar is a wrapper for standard WinApi window class, so by default the painting is done by OS. You should look into WinApi functions, or messages like SB_SETTEXT

Check this on MSDN: [SB_SETTEXT message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

It seems [DrawStatusText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the right WinApi function. SBT_NOBORDERS flag shall be specified if borders are not required.